# how to check individual android app's system resource info?

Tags: android, resources

As title described, I am trying to make an android app which can check on other app's

system resource usage info...for instance, mobile audio volume, network access ability...etc

Is there any android sdk library can help me accomplish such job ? I knew app like this

http://www.guidingtech.com/11501/monitor-app-activities-resource-usage-android/

is what I am trying to make ... Please give me some direction, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) provides some of the information You need. Checkouot its `getInstalledPackages` method and [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)